# Purpose of the wooden board in the ground

Tags: exterior, landscaping, lumber

Close to the foundation, there is a wooden board, I assume pressure-treated, in the ground. It looks pretty old and started to rot. I can't think of anything it is attached to. What purpose could it possibly serve? Is it fine if I remove it?

[image]

Comment: Is the board loose? It may just be leftover scrap or part of a pallet.

Comment: It's only a bit loose on the end towards the downspout. On the other end it is not.